# What is the best way to merge a branch into master AND another branch?

Tags: git, github

**Context**:

I have created a branch (let's call it `new-feature`), based off `master`. I plan to create a pull request that will remain open over the next few months.

During this time, I will be doing feature development by branching off of `new-feature`. Once a branch has been reviewed and approved, I will create a pull request to merge that bit of work into `new-feature`

When all is said and done, `new-feature` will be merged into `master`.

**My question**:

Let's say one of my `new-feature` child branches (let's call it `child-branch-1`) contains a change that *also* needs to be merged into `master` BEFORE `new-feature` is merged into `master`?

Am I able to use a single branch for this change, creating 2 separate pull requests (1 PR to  merge the change into `master`, and another PR to merge the change into `new-feature`, respectively), or is it better to use 2 different branches (1 based off of `master`, and 1 based off of `new-feature`, with a PR for each) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say one of my new-feature child branches (let's call it `child-branch-1`) contains a change that also needs to be merged into `master` BEFORE `new-feature` is merged into `master`?

That branch `child-branch-1` includes the history (in part) of `new-feature`.

You cannot merge `child-branch-1` as-is to master, because it includes too much.

- make a new branch from `upstream/master` (with upstream being the remote of the original repository you have forked)
- [`git cherry-pick` one or several commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309) from `child-branch-1` to that new branch
- make a separate PR from the new branch which, again, only includes the commits relevant to your "urgent" change.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly merge `child-branch-1` to master. Once I did that, I would then make a pull from `master` to `new-feature` that way you'd have the change you need in `new-feature` and the children of such branch would have the change too.

Since you need to have `child-branch-1` in master before you put it in `new-feature`, I think it's better to get `child-branch-1` from master instead of taking it from `new-feature`.

I'm speaking about this thinking of it as a simple general case, your personal case may be more complicated though. It may be possible that you need some things from `child-branch-1` to go to master, and some other things to go to `new-feature`. If that's case, I would use another approach, maybe you can tell us a few more details about your issue.